# Should I use BLPOP, or yield-based busy waiting on hundreds of redis keys?

Tags: multithreading, performance, redis, architecture, nosql

The former sounds good, but I have the following concerns:

- blocking hundreds of connections might be wasteful, e.g., io multiplexing strategy used, and
- the redis server should deal with more concurrent connections since each is long-running.

The alternative approach might be the latter:

- instead of busy waiting indefinitely, yield the thread at every `N`-th iteration.

Note that the number of connections would increase in proportion to the number of instances. Outside the two, a fixed pool of `BLPOP` executors can be introduced, but that could easily be the bottleneck if some of the redis list is idle.

Answer (score 0):

I/O multiplexing is not busy waiting

The BLPOP command is an actual command sent to Redis server which involves I/O multiplexing and not busy waiting in the client code

I don't see any point in busy waiting with or without thread yield

For an alternative I suggest using PUB/SUB function supported by Redis, just in case you need to wait on some other events beside list being empty

Comment: Thanks for your time! I also don't think `BLPOP` is busy-waiting. Depending on the I/O multiplexing strategy used, iterating all those file descriptors can be overhead. That's just one example I can think of. There might be other factors, like a multitude of TCBs created, or a housekeeping of those structures.

Comment: The point of yielding threads was to prevent busy-waiting `LPOP` from overly using CPU for empty redis lists. Also, redis Pub/Sub is great, but I want to avoid the cases where no consumer is alive and new items are dropped.